# How to make sure AsyncTask is executed

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, picasso

I'm pretty new to Android development, I feel like I have a relatively simple question here and have managed to tie down the more complex parts but overlook the more simple bits. I've setup an ImageAdapter class which handles displaying images into a GridView in another one of my Fragments. Originally I was following a tutorial that simply displayed a list of items in an Array.

I'm using an AsyncTask to populate an ArrayList, and then converting the ArrayList to a standard array that Picasso can deal with when displaying content.

My problem is that the AsyncTask section of my ImageAdapter is just not getting executed, thus my `imageArr[]` that Picasso uses is just remaining empty.

How can I make sure that the AsyncTask section of my Adapter is actually executed?

I've tried this, but it just doesn't seem to be working and I think I'm a little bit off...

```
    public void onCreate() {
    new GetProjects().execute();
}
```

I've attached my code bellow, any help would be really appreciated!

Note; ServiceHandler is just retrieving the data at the URL and then turning it into a string which can be parsed.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


//JSON URL
private static String url = "www.myjsonsourceurl.com";

//JSON NODES

private static final String TAG_LOGO = "logopath";

ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] imageArr = imageUrls.toArray(new String[imageUrls.size()]);


private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return imageArr.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


public void onCreate() {
    new GetProjects().execute();
}


// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    Picasso.with(mContext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(mContext).setLoggingEnabled(true);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageArr[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.ajaxloader).error(R.drawable.imageunavailable).into(imageView);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
//ASYNC task to get json by making HTTP call
public class GetProjects extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Nothing right now


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonStr);


                // looping through All Applications
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject p = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    String logopath = p.getString(TAG_LOGO);

                    imageUrls.add(logopath);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");


        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call in activity or fragment where list is defined not in adapter like this. move asynctask class to your activity and call it from there.

AsyncTask gives methods 
**onPreExecute()** and **onPostExecute()** where you can toast message that task is started or completed. And you should call setAdapter() in onPostExecute() of class.

Answer (score 0):

There`s no onCreate method for BaseAdapter which you can override. Execute your code

```
 new GetProjects().execute();
```

either in contructor or call your onCreate function (I suggest changing its name) manualy from outside of the adapter.